# make two divs overlap each other

Tags: html, css

I want to make two divs overlap each other using css. I used the following code but when some text or content is added to the blue box it overflows the gray box while I want to keep it inside the the gray box and stretch it as the inner content is stretched.

```css
.gray {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #818181;  
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
}  

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0090ff;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
  <div class="white">
    left text
  </div>  
  <div class="blue">
    <p>some text goes here</p>
    <p>some text goes here</p>
    <p>some text goes here</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

here is my satisfactory result:

[image]

How can I correct the css to get the above result?

Comment: Just use negative margin [like for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687949/overlap-background-image-from-one-section-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this.
The gray will autosize in height when you add more content to the blue div.You may need to change some with and margin values to get the layout you want, but the mechanism is there.

```
.gray {
    background-color: #818181;
    z-index: -1;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.white {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #0090ff;
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

See it work: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/dj9wo8ak/4/

Answer (score 0):

So you need to define blue box as position relative the overflow will be stopped and and when you add some content to blue div it will not overflow.

If you want to get white div under a blue div you need to set it to position:absolute and set it z-indx lesser than blue div has

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.gray {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #818181;  
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left; 
  width: 97%; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 2; 
  height: 50%; 
  left: 1%

}  

.blue {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0090ff;
  z-index:3;
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
  top: -9%;
  left: 8%;
}
```

Play with the height and width sizes to reach your desired dimensions.
Do the same with the position values to place the divs the way you want

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u50jj2e1/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
.gray {
  background-color: #818181;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Instead of hidden it could be "overflow: auto;"*/
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}  

.blue {
  background-color: #0090ff;
  top: 0;
  height: 290px;
  width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}  


<div class="gray">
  <div class="white">
  </div>  
  <div class="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

I create exact shape for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dj9wo8ak/1/

Comment: Everything is absolute and therefore will not stretch as OP requests.

Comment: You have used height attribute for gray box. If the content of blue class lengths more than 300px, the overflow is occurred.

Comment: @HamidGhorashi   `overflow: hidden;` added to answer. If you want to change height and width attributes of divs dynamically, you must add some JavaScript code.

Comment: @Daniel `overflow: auto;` I mentioned. Could you please take back your downvote.

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran - You are close. Change gray to "position:relative" and "height:auto" ... blue to "position:relative; float:left; height:auto;" Test that in fiddle and see that the div responds when more content is added to the blue div...